# Getting '(400) Bad Request' with GetResponseStream() in C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api, system.net, system.net.webexception

I am using the following code to send a get request to facebook graph api oauth server.

```
public string GetAccessToken(string code)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=249725835046216&redirect_uri=http://localhost:2794/&client_secret=APP_SECRETa&code=" + code);
        HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        string response=res.GetResponseStream().ToString();
        return response;
    }
```

The above code throws the following exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Meanwhile if I type the same url in browser, it works. Please help, where am I wrong?

(P.S In the URL, I am surely replacing APP_SECRET with the secret key)

Answer (score 2):

Your querystring parameters should be UrlEncoded:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=249725835046216&redirect_uri=" + UrlEncode("http://localhost:2794/") + "&client_secret=" + UrlEncode(APP_SECRET) + "&code=" + UrlEncode(code));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode the parameters of your URL. You could use the HttpUtility class
for encoding your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to specify user agent to satisfy some check logic of a server:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"https://...&code=" + code);
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
```

try this and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect URL needs to be the same as the one that you posten when getting a code.

Please check this article, helped me!
http://www.ronaldwidha.net/2011/03/24/facebook-oauth-access_token-return-http-400-error-validating-verification-code/

Answer (score 0):

This is what happened to me and how to solve that:

1. Redirect the user to

   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL
2. After user click allow, it'll hit our Redirect Uri
3. At that point we'll get the code and we need to do a server side
   HTTP Get to the following Url to exchange the code with our oAuth
   access token:

   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE

Now at step 3, I kept on getting Http 400 response back.

So after some research, I found out that on that `redirect_uri` that we submitted on `step 3` doesn't do anything but validate the request. Thus, the value **need to match** with step 2.

In short :

redirect_uri MUST MATCH both `step 2` and `step 3`